# Перехват нажатия ссылки на WebBrowser приложением c#

Tags: c#, html, .net, winforms

Есть приложение `abc.exe` и протокол `abc://param`, вызывающий это приложение с параметром `param`. В приложении используется `WebBrowser`, содержимое которого формируется с помощью `xslt`.

В этом WebBrowser будут ссылки с использованием протокола. Соответственно при нажатии на ссылку будет открываться `новый инстанс` приложения и выполняться действия, связанные с параметром. А как *перехватить* нажатие на ссылку и выполнить действия, связанные с параметром в `текущем инстансе` программы?

А на нажатие на ссылку с зажатой клавишей `SHIFT` в новом инстансе. В общем аналогично действиям браузера для ссылок.

Примеры

param << на нажатие текста `param` срабатывает протокол `abc://param`.

param2 << на нажатие текста `param2` срабатывает протокол `abc://param2`.

Comment: К сожалению ссылки не отобразились, поэтому я их расшифровал рядом.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать событие **[`Navigating`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigating%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)** контрола `WebBrowser`.
Событие вызывается при попытке браузера открыть новый документ, второй аргумент метода представляет из себя объект **[`WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowsernavigatingeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx)**, содержащий Uri нового документа.

Таким образом, событие может выглядеть следующим образом:

```
private void WebBrowser1_OnNavigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Url.Scheme != "abc") return;

    string url = e.Url.AbsoluteUri; // новый адрес, можно его распарсить
    e.Cancel = true; // отменить переход
}
```

Для перехвата открытия ссылки в новом окне (а также с зажатым Shift) необходимо использовать событие **[`NewWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.newwindow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)**. Однако, это событие не предоставляет адрес нового документа.

```
private void WebBrowser1_NewWindow(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    // доступен только e.Cancel
}
```

Есть несколько нетривиальных способов обойти это и получить адрес, однако их описание очень большое и доступно только на английском языке:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636961/how-to-get-the-new-windows-url-with-webbrowser
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14871235/get-url-for-webbrowser-newwindow-event
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/71592/How-to-easily-capture-the-NewWindow3-event-and-det

Comment: Здесь же аргументы события `e` будут также хранить и информацию о нажатой клавише, например, `SHIFT`?

Comment: @VladislavVitalyev Нет, событие `Navigating` вообще не будет срабатывать, если ссылку откроют в новом окне. С новым окном всё значительно сложнее. Я обновил ответ.

Answer (score -1):

1. Не использовать протокол `abc://` на странице.
2. Обрабатывать оба события перехода.

Comment: Поясните, пожалуйста, я к сожалению не до конца понял. Как тогда получать параметр, то есть тот текст, по которому произошло нажатие? Например, в том же случае с событием NewWindow?

Comment: @VladislavVitalyev, замени свой `abc://` на какой-нибудь `http://abc/`, тогда браузер будет пытаться перейти на ссылку и ты сможешь обработать событие перехода. Если не забуду, поищу вечером код.